# DLL that depends on other DLLs?

Tags: c++, deployment

Static linking is not an option.

Let's say that I have an executable that relies on a DLL. One solution is to ship the DLL in the same folder as the executable. Now let's say that I need to inject a DLL into a process that relies on a DLL. Because the DLL is injected, where would I put the DLLs that it relies on? In the same folder? Or in the directory of the process that is injected to?

Answer (score 7):

DLLs depending on one or more other DLLs is not something special. Even a trivial DLL will have dependencies on Windows shared components which are residing in other DLLs. A good example of these "shared components" would be `Kernel32.dll` and the CRT DLL such as `MSVCR80.DLL` etc.

You can find out exactly which other DLLs your DLL or EXE requires on by invoking the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). To do that, just run `depends.exe` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt and drag-and-drop the DLL of interest into the Window that appears. In case you don't have dependency walker available, you can download it from the above link.

I'm not sure of the DLL injection stuff, but it should generally be sufficient if you place all your (other DLL) dependencies in the same folder as your DLL, which would be the folder in which the EXE loading these DLLs resides.

Eg: If `C:\test\foo.exe` requires `bar.dll` (which in turn requires `baz.dll`, assuming `baz.dll` is not a standard windows shared component), then you would place both `bar.dll` and `baz.dll` in `C:\test`.

There is a lot more to how the OS determines which DLL to load, since multiple versions of the same DLL may exist at various locations and MSDN has a helpful [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the search order for dynamic linked libraries.

Comment: Yes, placing them in the same folder is the standard practice. If you absolutely need to put them elsewhere, call the `SetDllDirectory` function to modify the default search order for your application. Great answer!